# How to insert preprocessor value in a vector<int>?

Tags: c++, stl, c-preprocessor

```
#define HEADER = 5
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(HEADER);
  return 0;
}
```

why this code gives me a syntex error ?
as far as i preprocessor get treated like int.

Comment: Did you `#include <vector>`? Also use `std::vector<int> v;`

Comment: yes i did, if i insert 0 it compiles with no errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#define HEADER = 5` replaces `HEADER` with `= 5`
You want `#define HEADER 5` without `=`

Side note, don´t use non-standard `_tmain`.

```
#include <vector>  
#define HEADER 5
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(HEADER);
  return 0;
}
```

compiles without syntax errors.

Comment: @max Show the full message. `)` is no error message. And it compiles fine, eg. here: http://ideone.com/nUgdy7

Comment: error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
 error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Comment: @max You're using the wrong project mode for compiling. Probably change back to `_tmain()`, to get it compiled.